# Why is the result not adding up every time 1 occurs?

Tags: python

When n = 4, the binary = 100, so the result should be 1 but it still shows 0. Why?

```
def count_bits(n):
binary = format(n, "b")
result = 0
for i in binary:
    if i == 1:
        result = result + 1
return result
```

Comment: Can you show your function call?

Comment: What is your goal?

Comment: When you create the variable `binary`, it is a string, and when you loop through the characters of `binary` you will get strings. Your if statement `if i == 1:` is always false because `1` is not the same as the string `'1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you compare a non int i (1) to a int 1, which isnt the same so it never triggers your if statement.
here's your fix:

```
def count_bits(n):
    binary = format(n, "b")
    result = 0
    for i in binary:
        if int(i) == 1:
            result = result + 1
    return result
```

change the non int 1 (i) to an int.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to count numeric 1 in a string representation so you'll never find a match.

A shorter expression of the function could be:

```
def count_bits(n): return f"{n:b}".count("1")
```